# can't build OpenGL software on 14.10 with fglrx-updates: "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL"

Tags: compiling, 14.10, fglrx, opengl

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 on a new laptop with an "AMD A6-6310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics" type CPU/GPU. Due to freezing issues with Gallium3D, I installed fglrx-updates. Now because I like to play around with bleeding-edge GTK+ I tried to install that using jhbuid, however it fails to link cairo, giving me the dreaded

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

However, software that actually uses OpenGL works just fine (though glxgears neither shows/draws its window decoration nor lets me use the mouse to move the camera for some reason).

I also installed `fglrx-updates-dev`, to no avail.

What can I do to fix this issue besides creating a symbolic link myself (which I feel is a bit of a hack)? I have the header files in `/usr/include/GL`, so that's not an issue... There's also no `fglrx-glx` package so I can't just install that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I caved in, did the symbolic link, and it seemed to work fine... until pango decided to use the cairo-generated `pkg-config` file, which depends on an OpenGL `pkg-config` file that also isn't there with `fglrx`.

I've now filed [a bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1409366).